# Double-click instead of single-click in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mouse, click-policy

When I do a single click, my computer (with `Ubuntu 12.04`) acts like it was double click. I think it happens in  `~50%` of cases.

It happens with all the program I use: browsers, file manager, terminal and so on.
I'm not sure when exactly it started, maybe a week ago, and I don't remember if it started to happen after system-update or after the installation of some packages.

What I tried:

- change mouse
- change mouse settings like `Double-Click Timeout`

None of those helped me. Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

This bug has disappeared after upgrading to `12.10`.

Comment: This might be this open bug: [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/365300](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/365300)

Comment: Does it happen if you use live Ubuntu installation CD?

Comment: You can also make sure that it's not a hardware failure by simply trying out another mouse.

Comment: just ran into the same issue - had a dell mouse for a desktop PC; replaced it - and the fun was over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've manually edited `xorg.conf`, try adding and entry for your mouse, in case it was somehow deleted:

```
Section "InputDevice"
# generated from default
Identifier "Mouse0"
Driver "mouse"
Option "Protocol" "auto"
Option "Device" "/dev/psaux"
Option "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection
```

> Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1844513&page=2

**EDIT** As mention in the comments, this seems to be a reported bug that has stood for some time now. It may be best to add your info to Launchpad to help resolve the bug in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added this section to `xorg.conf` but it didn't help :(

Comment: I copied and pasted straight from the forum, so you may want to check the settings I've provided to match what you have.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same happen to me for no apparent reason a few days ago on 12.04. I went to nautilus Preferences..Behaviour and it had "Double click" option selected. I then selected single click, checked that was working, then went back and changed to double click again and bingo! Its back in double click mode!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04.

**Solution:**
If you are using a laptop try taking out its battery and then inserting it back.

**Explanation:**
The problem was possibly caused by battery of my laptop. I noticed that though my laptop was fully charged and plugged in, its battery LED was changing color between orange (indicating charging) and yellow (indicating fully charged) continuously. So I removed my battery and inserted back to its slot (didn't switch off my laptop, so everything else remained same). This solved the issue, and since then the touch-pad is working perfectly fine.